# Rails - cookies value doesnt persist across actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am trying to save a data on cookies that can be used later.

```
def hello
  name = SecureRandom.hex
  cookies[:cookies_name] = name
  .....
end

def process_file
  logger.debug "The number of lines in specific is updr #{cookies[:cookies_name] }"
   ...
end
```

In action process_file, the value I stored in cookies is spaces (nil). Moreover, using developer tool when I am trying to see the cookies (Chrome -> developer tool -> resources), i cant see any cookies.

How do I set cookies?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting expiry date for your cookie

```
cookies[:cookies_name] = {value: name, expires: 1.year.from_now}
```

Comment: did you check the value of your `name` variable? maybe that is `nil` so it will be the value stored to your cookie

Comment: Hi Lymuel -the variable "name" is not nil. I can see the value of name in log file.